# npm run prettier --check differ with that in azure pipeline task

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, azure-devops, prettier

> I'm working on a react app, deployed and maintained through azure
> devops. When I run prettier locally by command **npm run
> format:check** then all files are formatted with message as All
> matched files use Prettier code style!. But in azure pipeline I added
> npm installer, with Command and arguments as **run format:check** , but it shows that Code style issues found in n files. Forgot to run Prettier?

```
 package.json 

 "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "format:check": "prettier --check ."
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest-editor-support": "^30.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "playwright": "^1.25.2",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this issue all day. My issue was to do with using a Windows build agent which (I now believe) is converting the LF line endings to CRLF.

My solution was to have a different script for the build agent version of this in the package.json.

```
"format:check:pipeline": "prettier --end-of-line crlf --check ."
```

Answer (score 0):

Which files does it say still need to be formatted? I'm guessing that these will be files which are generated at some point during the pipeline (e.g. `node_modules`, or build artifacts).

If so, the solution would be adding those files to the [.prettierignore file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files-prettierignore)